# How do I return a value from a function where the type of the passed variables aren't the same

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to comapre two values and return the differences.
I am getting an error `ByRef argument type mismatch`
This error seems to be triggered by Null values, while I defined them `as String` in the function.
The thing is that not all cells contain values.

However, I am not sure how to circumvent this problem

Below a simplified example of my situation

```
Sub MacroX()
    For Each C In Sheets("ADG 2020").Range("C6:C50")
        PI2020 = Sheets("ADG 2020").Cells(C.Row, C.Column + 7).Value
        For Each CC In Sheets("ADG 2018").Range("C6:C50")
            PI2018 = Sheets("ADG 2018").Cells(CC.Row, CC.Column + 7).Value
            Worksheets("ADG 2020").Cells(C.Row, C.Column + 12).Value = CHARDIF(PI2020, PI2018)
        Next CC
    Next C
End Sub

Public Function CHARDIF(ByRef rngA As String, rngB As String)
    Dim strA As String, strB As String
    Dim i As Long, strTemp As String
    strA = rngA
    strB = rngB
    If Len(strA) > Len(strB) Then
        strTemp = strA
        strA = strB
        strB = strTemp
        strTemp = ""
    End If
        
    For i = 1 To Len(strB)
        If i > Len(strA) Then
            strTemp = strTemp & Mid(strB, i, 1)
        ElseIf UCase(Mid(strA, i, 1)) <> UCase(Mid(strB, i, 1)) Then
            strTemp = strTemp & Mid(strB, i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    
    CHARDIF = strTemp
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the next approach, please:

In `MacroX` sub, declare the used variables as string. Otherwise, they are of type Variant and may create confusions:

```
Dim PI2020 As String, PI2018 As String
```

Then your function does not need to change string variables between each other:

```
Public Function CHARDIF(strA As String, strB As String) As String
    Dim i As Long, strTemp As String
    If Len(strA) > Len(strB) Then
        strTemp = strA
        strA = strB
        strB = strTemp
        strTemp = ""
    End If
        
    For i = 1 To Len(strB)
        If i > Len(strA) Then
            strTemp = strTemp & Mid(strB, i, 1)
        ElseIf UCase(Mid(strA, i, 1)) <> UCase(Mid(strB, i, 1)) Then
            strTemp = strTemp & Mid(strB, i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    
    CHARDIF = strTemp
End Function
```

Comment: Of course, so simple, but I wasn't able to solve it. Thank you very much FaneDuru!

Comment: @MK01111000: Glad I could help!